# Krita art tablet pen inputs cut out and switch to mouse

Tags: drivers, graphics-tablet, krita

So... I can't really do digital art right now because every now and then, when working in Krita, a pen stroke on my art tablet will be cut out and moving the mouse cursor will draw instead. (One time I tried making a drawing and the first stroke was immediately cut out, leaving just a dot on the canvas.)

Here're the facts:

- At first I thought it was unfocusing, but it still said Krita as the focused window top left, and the only reason ctrl-z etc didn't work was that the program thought a stroke was ongoing.
- I have experimented with Aseprite and GIMP (with pressure dynamics) using my art tablet and neither program has this issue.
- Canvas-only mode doesn't fix the problem.
- I first noticed it on 2023-01-25.
- No settings or anything were changed by me that could have caused this as far as I know.
- I'm on Krita 5.1.5 now, the problem started on 5.1.1 and didn't stop when I updated.
- I'm using a Krita AppImage.
- I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS, Gnome version 42.5.
- My art tablet is a Wacom Intuos Draw (I think is the name), and it is quite a few years old. Maybe about 6, 7 years old?
- There is no line connecting the end of the pen stroke and the beginning of the mouse cursor stroke if that makes any difference.

I've asked on the Krita help forums but it's looking mostly like a driver issue according to those there, so I'm asking here: how can I fix this?

Comment: So it turns out that it's my choice of graphics driver, but I can't install a few of them (empty error message pops up), and when I install some that work, after reboot it shows that I've installed another, and one that did work gave me blurry textures in vulkan gzdoom... the whole thing is broken, I need to reinstall Ubuntu.